# Get current language that is used in another application using java

Tags: java, locale, awtrobot

I'm learning `java.awt.Robot` and want to select my browser window, click in address bar and enter address.
So to enter said address I need to make sure that current language used in browser is English.

I tried this:

```
String s = InputContext.getInstance().getLocale().getLanguage();
System.out.println(s);
decker.changeLanguage();
s = InputContext.getInstance().getLocale().getLanguage();
System.out.println(s);
```

But both times I get:

```
en
en
```

Although I can see in real time the language is changing. Can I get the language that is currently used in window that I'm currently controlling with my application.